# Updated iphone application not live yet

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

3 weeks back we uploaded an application on the iTunes(V1.0). On Thursday we updated that application with new build (V1.2). I clicked the "Update" button on itunesconnect.apple.com and followed uploaded the new binary and new contents.

On the next day the Description and price tag are updated successfully, but the build version number and screens shots are still from the previous version. And the amazing thing we noticed is that application status is "Waiting for Review" from last 2 days... :(

I tried to play with release date, but still application status is "Waiting for Review".

Its been 2 days that there is no activity happening from apple... :(

Please help me in this scenario.....

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vishal.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the App Store. Apple has to approve all apps and new versions before they can go up. This can take some time. For some devs it has taken upward of a month. Lately they've been better about response time, but it's still basically out of your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Once new version of App is submitted for review all you can do is wait for Apple to approve it. From my own experience (5 Mobile App Releases so far) approval time is always different however usually takes between 3-7 days.